# C++: Vector members destructed after vector populated in class constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Yes I've searched but I can't find the answer.  I have a vector that is a member of a class.  This vector is given some values (in this case just 1) in the class constructor.  As soon as the constructor is finished, the destructor for the objects in the vector is called.

Here's a short and sweet version of what I'm dealing with

test.h

```
Class test
{
  private:
    Vector<Sprite> sprites;
  public:
    test(item _something);
}
```

test.cpp

```
test::test(item _something);
{
  sprites.emplace_back(_device, tBank["TestTexture"]);
}
```

main.cpp

```
test testItem;

main()
{
  testItem = testItem(something);
  // This is where the destructor for sprite is called
}
```

I know the code above doesn't work but it's a shorthand of what is going on.  I can post the whole thing if requested.  Anyway am I doing something crazy?

Comment: Is that an std::vector? Why is the Class keyword uppercase?

Comment: I assume you mean `testItem = test(something);`? And what is `Vector` (uppercase V)? Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: You should copy real code, and make sure that it is valid (where is the return type of `main`?)

Comment: Your code has so many holes in it that it's not possible to help much. show some real code, please (but not *too* much!)

Comment: Yes this is not the real code.  I posted that at the bottom.  I'm usually dealing with C# not C++ and figured people wouldn't want to read through a few pages of code.  Sorry to create so much confusion, I'll post "this is not real code" at the top next time, or just post pages of code either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I assume with `testItem(something)` you actually mean `test(something)` (there are a number of other obvious errors, e.g., `main()` need to to return `int`, i.e., it seems this isn't the real code).

When you assign the temporary created with `test(something)` to `testItem` the object is copy or move assigned to `testItem` and, next, the temporary is destroyed. The compiler doesn't have much choice to do otherwise. The contained `std::vector<Sprite>` can be moved if there is no copy constructor or copy assignment in your `test` class. Since that isn't the real code, it's hard to tell.

Comment: OK, sounds like this could be what's going on.  Since there is no way around this there is a problem since part of sprite is a DirectX   LPD3DXSPRITE which the destructor is destroying, meaning that the copies pointer (or original, whichever survives) ends up pointing to nothing if the destructor is called.

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is expected:

```
Type t;
t = Type(arg);
```

The second line creates an object of type `Type` with the given arguments, it then assigns it to the `t` variable. At the end of the complete expression, the temporary is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.  I'm not sure how I'm going to get around this.